# CLI in http header

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have to integrate a 3rd party system into my PHP app. I'm using cURL. The documentation says I have to send a soap envelope to the server, but in their example I found the following HTTP header as a correct request:

```
POST /CLI/ HTTP/1.1

Host: example.com
```

What's that CLI in the header? How can I send such a request from PHP?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the resource being requested,

```
GET /index.php
POST /index.php
```

IN your case: POST http://example.com/CLI/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol